# In Azure DevOps which ticket was a branch created for?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps you can select a ticket on the Sprint task board and there is a menu option `Create Branch` which you can use to create a branch in the repo to work on that ticket.

Having done this, if you go to the `Branches` view in DevOps, how on earth do you see which ticket each branch was created for?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your concern and description, currently, on the Branches view in DevOps, there is no optioned field for which ticket each branch was created for, also, regarding this limit for your "*`Branches view show which ticket each branch was created for`*" requirement, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Besides, a workaround for your scenario is that it is suggested that you could name the branch with the related WIT ID to help recognize it, for example, you can name the new created branch like WIT ID "Task6" to help specify the branch when creating it.

Pic1:
[image]

Pic2:
[image]

You could also check the related branch name in "Details" and "History" section when opening the WIT.

In "Details" section.
[image]

In "History" section.
[image]

Hope it's helpful to you.